# AWS: Can the Elastic Transcoder signal SWF?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flash, amazon-elastic-transcoder

We're using SWF to take videos through a lengthy process, part of which includes sending them through the Elastic Transcoder.

It looks like the Elastic Transcoder can send an SNS notification when it's complete, but I don't see any way for it to signal the SWF so the process can continue.

From what I can tell, the only options are (A) set up a URL that SNS can ping when the transcode completes; this URL runs a script which signals the SWF.  Or (B) have SNS send a message into SQS, and write a worker process to constantly check the queue for completed transcodes, and signal the SWF.

Neither of those options seems that pleasing.  Ideal would be if the Elastic Transcoder (or SNS) could signal the SWF directly.  Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, it would seem, is no.

Comment: Wondering if you found the solution because there are more and more encoding service providers :)

Comment: No there didn't seem to be a solution.  Though I am now curious of AWS Lambda would do it.